# set background color for body depending on if/else statement

Tags: php, css

I don't know if this is possible but I want to know if I can set the background color of a page depending on an if/else statement?

What I want is that if the if statement is met, then I want the background color of the body to be white, if the else statement is met where it contains a div, then I want the background color of the body to be grey.

Can this be done?

```
      <?php

if (page()){

//all the code in the page

}else{
?>

<div class="boxed">


</div>

<?php   

}

?>
```

UPDATE:

```
<?php

        if (page()){
?>

    <body class="bodypage <?php echo page()? "color1":"color2" ?>" >

    </body>

<?php

    }else{

    <div class="boxed">
    <a href="<?php echo $pages[$currentPages+1] ?>">Continue with Current Assessment</a>
    </div>

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be. How about you use a predefined class that have the background color you need:

```
.color1 {
   background-color:red;
}
.color2 {
   background-color:yellow;
}

<body class="boxed <?php echo page()? "color1":"color2" ?>" >

</body>
```

#### UPDATE:

```
<body class="bodypage <?php echo page()? "color1":"color2" ?>" >
<?php if (page()){?>
... all the page code
<?php else {?>
<div class="boxed">
   <a href="<?php echo $pages[$currentPages+1] ?>">Continue with Current Assessment</a>
</div>
?>
```

Comment: Hi, I want the page to change color, not the box to change colour. Your code is changing colour of the box

Comment: I included an update to show condition, I think you are right, I am messing up with the condition

Answer (score 0):

A zillion ways to do this.

PHP:

```
$bodyClass = $condition ? 'foo' : 'bar';
...
echo <<< END_HTML
    <body class="$bodyClass">
       <!-- stuff here -->
    </body>
END_HTML;
```

CSS:

```
body.foo { background-color:#fff; }
body.bar { background-color:#888; }
```

..is one way to do it.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<body <?php if(true) {echo('style="background:red"'); } else { echo('style="background:white"'); } ?> >

</body>
```

Comment: this just echos the statement, it doesn't change the colour

Comment: Yes I did and that's what happend. Can you just put your code in my if statement so I can see what it looks like in my if statement but Im sure I placed it correctly in if/else function

Comment: Note that the code is in the body tag. There is no body tag in your question

Comment: Ahh, I do have a body tag in application but did not see you put it in a body tag. Let me try again

Comment: OK Id `<body <?php if(allowed_in()) {echo('style="background:red"'); } else { echo('style="background:blue"'); } ?> >`, didn't work, I did your exact line of code and that did not work as well

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way using javascript & jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(condition){
  if (cond) {
    $(body).css("background-color","red");
  } else {
    $(body).css("background-color","blue");
  }
});
</script>
```

Or in php you can just echo that code, with some changes.

Comment: What is the php version of doing the above?

Comment: There could be any php version. As I remember `echo` was since the beginning and does not require something special.

Comment: @Johnny No I meant is the php equivalent `echo (body).css("background-color","red");`?

Comment: It would look like that:
<? if (smth) {
echo "<script>doSmth();</script>";
}
?>
As far as php has nothing to do with html page except echo, you should use it. And insert this script right where u need the script to be executed. And actual answer is no, there is no such equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Try to minimize the php influence on your design. (CSS for design, html for semantics, php for structure and javascript for interaction)

To accomplish this I recommend sending a hidden input to the browser containing a value:

```
if(statement) {
  $color = '#ffffff';
} else {
  $color = '#ff0000';
}

echo '<input id="pageColor" type="hidden" value="'.$color.'" />';
```

Now do the following with (for example) jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //change bg color based on input value
  $('body').css('background-color', $('#pageColor').val());
});
```

Comment: it is giving me syntax error ); strangley enough even tho brackets seem fine

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can do this.

One of the most elegant ways:

PHP part:

```
<?php
$style = 'background:'; # property
$given = page() ? 'red;' : 'black;'; # Ternary operator
$style .= $given; # Concatenate two strings
?>
```

HTML part:

```
<div class="boxed" style='<?php echo $style; ?>'></div>
```

Also you can create special CSS classes with predefined variety of CSS properties:

PHP part:

```
<?php
$class = page() ? 'first' : 'second'; # CSS classes defined in your stylesheet.
?>
```

HTML part:

```
<div class="boxed <?php echo $class;?>"></div>
```

And here you go. That's just a quick demonstration, you can replace this with you parameters.